# Angular ui-router with express

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, angular-ui-router

I have set up ui router with the following states:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

$stateProvider
.state('adminprojects', {
    url: '/adminprojects',
    templateUrl: 'views/adminProjects.html',
    controller: 'adminProjectsCtrl'
})
.state('adminprojectsdetails', {
    url: '/adminprojects/:id',
    templateUrl: 'views/adminProjectsDetails.html',
    controller: 'adminProjectsDetailsCtrl'
})
```

adminprojects view contains a list with ui-sref links. eg

```
<li><a ui-sref="adminprojectsdetails({id: project.id})" href="/adminprojects/1">Project 1</a></li>
```

If I click this link for example adminprojects/1 the adminProjectsDetails.html view is shown correctly. However if I refresh this page or navigate directly to this url then the view does not load.

This however works as expected if I have html5 mode set to false;

In express I have this

```
router.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});
```

Controller are just pretty much boilerplate for now:

```
angular.module('jhApp')
.controller('adminProjectsCtrl', function($scope, projects) {
    $scope.projects = projects.items;
});
```

and

```
angular.module('jhApp')
.controller('adminProjectsDetailsCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {
    console.log($stateParams);
});
```

Any ideas why this is not working?

Comment: When comparing the [html5 server settings](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode) with your redirect... there is sume */public/* subfolder... maybe this could be the issue *(relative path)*. Could not you experiment with `index.html` placement? ... *ALSO side NOTE: do not use both `ui-sref` and `href`. Just one should be choosen...*

Comment: Could you show us the code of the controllers?

Comment: Sorry I was not clear, I only used ui-sref. href was added by ui-router.

Comment: I have tried changing the express route to: 
res.sendfile('index.html', { root: 'public' });
no change. If I remove the public in either option I get Error: ENOENT beacuse the path is wrong I think

Comment: Put <base href="/"/> tag inside your HEAD element above all other elments and try again.

Comment: adding the base tag fixes the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you create your project generator-angular ?

If so put `<base href="/"/>` inside your HEAD above all other elements.

Generator angular create index.html using relative paths for src folders like :

```
<script src="xxx/yyy.js"/>
```

When you refresh the page , browser looking for /adminprojects/xxx/yyy.js (.css , *) file which is not found. Because of that you can get lots of script and style errors. Using base tag fixes that problem.

Or simply just change your all src locations to "xxx/yyy.*" -> src="/xxx/yyy.*"